# Ranking the current day in PHP automatically

Tags: php

**Attempt:**

The following code prints the current day of the respective date.

```
<?php
$current_date = date("D");
echo $current_date;
?>
```

**Output:**

The above code gives the following output as: 
(As of date: 6/19/2018)

```
Tue
```

**Required Output:**

How can I rank the day automatically as:

```
Sun1
Mon2
Tue3
Wed4
Thu5
Fri6
Sat7
```

**Required Output Example:**

Instead of getting the output as *Tue* only. What I want the output is *Tue3* or similar type.

Suppose today is *Tuesday* as of (6/19/2018). Then I want the output as:

```
Tue3
```

Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: $day_no = date('N');

Comment: @ParthShah N flag: 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

- `w` = Numeric representation of the day of the week (0 Sun, 6 Sat).
- `D` = A textual representation of a day, three letters.

+1 the `w`, to give you the right number, then append it.

```
<?php
$rank = date("w")+1;
echo date("D").$rank;
```

**Result:**

`Tue3`

Comment: This is the required solution that I need. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: No worries, happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Hello You can archive by this way

```
echo date('D').(date('w')+1);
```

Please refer for more info http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: This would read for Sunday: Sun-7, not quite what the OP was asking for.   N flag: 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday).

Comment: @Progrock you are right may be it was slight mistake by me thanks for point out

Comment: Good amendment, but now it's just a clone of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50921548/3392762